# Pass form data in controller MVC React.net Core 1.1

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller

i'm a new user of React.net core .
I wanted to know how pass form's data between my form in my react file to the controller . I want to pass this data in controller . i have a model for "alert" with each attribute that we can see in the form . Then i want to store this data in a json that i create one time and rewrite each time i create a new alert. Thx for reading this.

```
    var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
        return (
        <div className="Header">

                <h1><strong>René</strong></h1>


                <div className="Creation">
                <hr />
                <strong><h2>Création d'une Alerte</h2></strong>
                <br />
                <br />

                <div className="container">
                    <form action="/Controllers/HomeController" method="post">
                        <label htmlFor="nom">Nom de l'Alerte</label>
                        <div className="col-xs-2">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nom"></input>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="descr">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="comment"></input>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="descr">Date de début</label>
                            <input type="date" className="form-control" name="dated"></input>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="descr">Date de fin</label>
                            <input type="date" className="form-control" name="datef"></input>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="panel panel-default">
                                <div className="panel-body">Niveau de l'Alerte</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <select className="selectpicker">
                            <option name="medium" className="medium" value="medium">Medium</option>
                            <option name="urgent" className="urgent"  value="urgent">Urgent</option>
                            <option name="turgent" className="turgent"  value="Turgent">Très Urgent</option>
                            <option name="critique" className="critique" value="Critique">Critique</option>
                        </select>

                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="panel panel-default">
                            <div className="panel-body">Type d'Alerte</div>
                        </div>
                        <p></p>
                        <span className="label label-success">Mail</span>
                        <input name="mail" type="checkbox" value="Mail" />
                        <br />
                        <p></p>
                        <span className="label label-info">Slack</span>
                        <input name="slack" type="checkbox" value="Slack" />
                        <br />
                        <p></p>
                        <span className="label label-primary">Ecran TV</span>
                        <input name="ecran" type="checkbox" value="Ecran" />
                        <br />
                        <p></p>
                        <span className="label label-warning">Sonnette</span>
                        <input name="sonnette" type="checkbox" value="Sonnette" />
                        <br />
                        <p></p>
                        <span className="label label-danger">Girophare</span>
                        <input name="girophare" type="checkbox" value="Girophare" />


                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default"  value="Submit Alert">Valider</button>

                        </form>


        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: If someone can help me i can give more details about my project and sorry for my english .